# Pass through KendoUI DatePicker Value through to the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm having a bit of an issue passing the value from a KendoUI DatePicker through to the controller

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
          .Name("FromDate")
          .Max(DateTime.Today)
          .Value(DateTime.Today)
          .Events(e => e.Change("change"))
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
        )
```

I want the value to be passed along when the read.Action event is called from the report Grid

```
@(Html.Kendo()
  .Grid<model>()
  .Name("AccountEditTraceability")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      //columns.bound....etc
  }
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .Model(model =>
              {
                  model.Id(aetr => aetr.Id);
              })
              .Read(read => read.Action("DisplayResults", "AccountEditTraceability", "FromDate")))
```

And in the controller use this value...

```
public ActionResult DisplayResults([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, DateTime filterByDate)
{
    //Do stuff with date
    var reportResults = AccountEditTraceabilityReport.Calculate(filterByDate);
}
```

Many thanks for any assistance to a noob mvc/kendo tinkerer.

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do following thing:

```
.Read(read => read.Action("DisplayResults", "AccountEditTraceability").Data("ReadRequestData")))
```

ReadRequestData is a javascript function which prepare your request data and should looks like:

```
function ReadRequestData () {
    return {
        "filterByDate": $("#FromDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value()
    };
}
```

Should work! But **be aware of date format**, beacuse there could be a lot of issues with sending date from client to server because of formats.

To be more specific I sent stringified JSON data to server and then I have different kind of problems with deserializing whole data beacuse of date formats. If you'll seek through the Internet there is a lot articles about issues related to JSON vs .NET DateTime.

Comment: Additionally you can format the date the way you need it via the kendo.format method. http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/kendo#methods-format

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was going nuts since I couldn't get it to work but a ticket through to Telerik verified that there is currently a bug in the latest release but that it has been resolved and applied to an internal build.